# JQuery DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am creating one web application. here I am facing one issue with jQuery.

Actually in my concept when user clicks on the Plus button one new row will be added. When user clicks on the minus button that specific row will be deleted. Row is having drop down lists and text boxes in it. Depending upon user selection the  will be created. It may be text box or drop down list box. If it is a textbox I need to create a datepicker. When user clicks on that textbox That textbox should be created dynamically.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you try to clarify in separate sections: what are you trying to achieve, what have you done to achieve it, what is working and what is not?

Comment: hi give some example code for this

Hi Row should create dynamically with date picker text box.It is working in the existing text box but when i create new row there I could not get date picker it is problem . 

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After you add the row, you need to attach the datepicker to your textbox. Something like this should be run after the element is created:

```
$('.date_input').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
```

Comment: Hi Row should create dynamically with date picker text box.It is working in the existing text box but when i create new row there I could not get date picker it is problem .

Comment: Hi Row should create dynamically with date picker text box.It is working in the existing text box but when i create new row there I could not get date picker it is problem .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of jquery you are using:

The key detail is how you tell jquery to attach to an item which does not exist yet.

In 1.3 and up, you use a [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) on the datepicker div name, so that it knows to create the datepicker.

If using an older version (1.2 and lower), you create a jquery object that is your text, and then attach the listener to the jquery object. Killerphps ajax with jquery video ["Dom Manipulation"](http://www.killerjavascript.com/beginners-jquery/) has a great walkthrough about how to do it.

Comment: Hi Row should create dynamically with date picker text box.It is working in the existing text box but when i create new row there I could not get date picker it is problem .

Comment: Please do not spam comment responses. I understand the issue.
Did you try using .live, like I mentioned?
Did you try a simple callback that would re-run the datepicker query?

$(event).(function(){do the typical thing; $(div).datepicker;})

Answer (score 0):

suppose your textbox element is like this:

```
<input type="text" ..... />
```

then add a css-class (if it does not contains one already and this should not be used with other kind of elements only with textboxes for datepicker) like this:

```
<input type="text" class="dtp" .... />
```

In you jquery code that adds new row:

```
var lastRow=$("table tr:last");//get newly added row some way.

$(lastRow).find("td input:text").datepicker();
```

Comment: Hi here two box is coming , I need to mention class name right?
is it correct
 $(lastRow).find("td classname").datepicker();

Comment: Hi
I am getting date picker is not defined error . plz help me ya.
i am in the verge.

thanks in advance

Comment: $(newRow).find(".date-pick").datepicker({startDate:'01/01/1996'});
Hi is it correct ont

Comment: Yes @shalini `$(newRow).find(".date-pick").datepicker({startDate:'01/01/1996'});` will work just as fine. you need to include `ui.datepicker.js` and Style Sheets from `jQuery.ui` package.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and managed to come up with a workaround.

I noticed that when I did the clone() on my tr the original DatePicker input (input.date) was cloned, complete with the "hasDatePicker" class. Removing this class and re-running .datepicker() on the tr solved it.

Sample code is:

```
tr.find('input.date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an exclusive idea-
where you are inserting those dynamic elements; just run the datePicker function there.
Here is a solution. Just take a look in **brief**.

for example-

- I have 2 datepicking textboxes( class="date" ) at very firsttime; within this div

`<div id="additional_charges">

         Startdate : <input type="text" name="startdate_1" class="date" /><br/>

         Enddate : <input type="text" name="enddate_1" class="date" />

</div>`

- Now On a event of some button, new contents( some more **datepicking text-boxes** )will be added into this div. Now, just run the date-picker method here also ( you know why ).
  `function add_more_charge()

  {

  var str = '<br/>Startdate : <input type="text" name="startdate_2" class="date" /><br/>Enddate : <input type="text" name="enddate_2" class="date" />';

  $("#additional_charges").append(str);

  $( ".date" ).datepicker(); // run the date-picker here also

  }`
- Now you are done, this following method is enough for you-
  `$(function() {

      $( ".date" ).datepicker();

  });`

*It's  my first post in this useful site. Don't know before, how much tough it is- to post something. Sorry for that List-View. Wanted to do some other thing. Thanks.*